# Mininet Ping issue

Tags: linux, networking, dns, mininet

Is it possible to ping mininet ip? I found mininet's ip starts with 10.0.2.15 . I can ping from mininet to others. However, I failed to ping other place to mininet. How can I setup this?

Comment: how is this programming related?

Comment: I am writing script for this. However, I failed to ping. That's why I need a solution to make Mininet public address

Answer (score 0):

10.0.0.0/8, which is 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 are IP addresses used only locally, they are not accessed from the internet (other networks). Here is some info from IANA:

> These addresses are in use by many millions of independently operated networks, which might be as small as a single computer connected to a home gateway, and are automatically configured in hundreds of millions of devices. They are only intended for use within a private context and traffic that needs to cross the Internet will need to use a different, unique address.
>
> These addresses can be used by anyone without any need to coordinate with IANA or an Internet registry. The traffic from these addresses does not come from ICANN or IANA. We are not the source of activity you may see on logs or in e-mail records.

Comment: Can I make it public address so that I can ping Mininet? Is it possible?